# Using an API to place markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, google-maps

for the last days i have been trying to place markers on google maps using a Json dataset. I have done this before using another datasett, and i cant seem to find out what it is i am doing wrong. 
This is the code i am using (also with a link to the datasett) 
I would love some input so i could figure out what's wrong.

```
function initMap() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&countrycode=NO&maxresults=*';
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    xhr.Data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (this.status == 200) {
        xhr.Data.forEach(poi => {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 60.391011, lng: 5.325950},
            zoom: 4
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < poi.AddressInfo; i++) {
            var data = xhr.Data.poi[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.AddressInfo.latitude, data.AddressInfo.longitude);

            //Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,

            });
        }
    })
    }
}
xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < poi.AddressInfo; i++) {` what are you expecting to happen here? `poi.AddressInfo` is an object.

Comment: Right... get rid of the `for()` loop

Comment: The idea of the for loop is to be able to iterate through all the POI points of the API to get all the points, how would i do this without that loop?

Comment: I fixed a few problems for you. Look carefully at where the `map` variable is defined and how I access the latitude and longitude (javascript is case sensitive). https://jsfiddle.net/x4gM4/674/

Comment: _"how would i do this without that loop"_ - you are already in a `forEach` loop: `xhr.Data.forEach(poi => { ... }`

Comment: Thank you so much Turnip, this worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your current code. See the numbered comments in the code below.

1. You should initialise your map outside of the `forEach` loop (2). Currently you are reinitialising your map for every poi.
2. I've removed the `for()` loop entirely. You are already looping over the poi's using `forEach` so the for loop is unnecessary.
3. You already have a `poi` object provided by the `forEach(poi =>)` so there is no need to use `var data = xhr.Data.poi[i]` to access the same object.
4. JavaScript is case-sensitive. The `Longitude` and `Latitude` properties of the `AddressInfo` object use title case so you must use title case to access the properties.

```js
function initMap() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&countrycode=NO&maxresults=*';
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    xhr.Data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    // (1)
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 60.391011,
        lng: 5.325950
      },
      zoom: 4
    });

    if (this.status == 200) {

      // (2)
      xhr.Data.forEach(poi => {

        // (3)
        // (4)
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(poi.AddressInfo.Latitude, poi.AddressInfo.Longitude);

        //Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,

        });
      })
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x4gM4/674/)